# Attack roll bonus for Orb implement?

Tags: dnd-4e, implements, psionics

I made a Psion class with the Dungeon's and Dragon's Character Builder for level 2. It is showing on all of my special moves that the prof bonus from my non magical orb as +6. Is this right? Should I get a bonus to my attack rolls for proficiency with my orb and how much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, it's correct.**

Implements do not provides proficiency bonus the way weapons do. That's because Implement attacks usually target a non-AC defense (a.k.a NAD). Fortitude, Reflex, and Will defenses are usually, but not always, lower than the typical AC.

Magical implements adds their enhancement bonus to the attack and damage rolls.

Your +6 so includes a +1 for half your level, the ability bonus of the ability tied to the power (usually Intelligence for Psion powers) and, possibly, some +1 bonus provided by "accuracy" feat(s) you took.